# type 'MappedListIterable<TotalPaymentListModel, DateTime?>' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast

Tags: flutter, datetime, flutter-layout, flutter-test

> This is what I wanted as on UI.

[image: This is what I wanted as on UI.]

> This is my formatter

```
static String formatMonthToYear(DateTime? date, BuildContext context){
    if (date == null) return "Invalid date";
    var formatter = DateFormat('yMMMM');
    return formatter.format(date);
  }
```

> I want to put date time here in Text.

```
Text(DateTimeUtil.formatMonthToYear(invoiceTotal.data!.map((e) => e.dueDate) as DateTime, context),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'quicksand_bold',
                          fontSize: 20
                      ),
                    ),
```

> This is the data i'm passing.

```
dueDate: json["due_date"] == null? null: DateTime.parse(json["due_date"]),
```

Comment: Guy please help me, thanks in advanced. ^^

Comment: Can you please elaborate that what is expected result you need

Comment: i want it like an image i put above

Comment: Whatever data you are giving in your formatted its not of `DateTime` datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

```
 static String formatMonthToYear(DateTime? date){ // <=== change here because you do not need to pass context.
        if (date == null) return "Invalid date";
        var formatter = DateFormat('yMMMM');
        return formatter.format(date);
      }
```

Then try this...

```
Text(DateTimeUtil.formatMonthToYear(invoiceTotal.data!.map((e) => DateTime.parse(e.dueDate).toString())),// <=== change here 
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontFamily: 'quicksand_bold',
                          fontSize: 20
                      ),
                    ),
```

because when you are passing Date it is in String so rather then assign as DateTime above is better way to do.

Comment: Thank you for helping but sadly this isn't working, I've tried different method too. for your following code i recived this as error: The argument type 'DateTime?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Comment: DateTime.parse(e.dueDate.toString())
please change this sorry for my mistake.

try this solution.